# How to read user input in Python

Tags: python, input

I'm beginner in Python and I'm trying to read two numbers in a simple programming contest problem.

```
# Codeforces New Year 2013 Contest;
# http://codeforces.com/contest/379/problem/A

import sys;

def main ():
    a = input ();
    b = input ();
    resto = 0;
    result = 0;

    while (a > 0):
        a-=1
        result += 1;
        resto += 1;

        if (resto >= b):
            resto -= b;
            a += 1;

    print result;

main ();
```

if I try to run the program with 4 2 (separated by a blank space), I get the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 2'

But if I type 4 [enter] and then 2 [enter], the program runs without any problems.

How do I read from stdin in python just like C++ does?

Edit: Sorry for the mess! I usually run a code with input this way:

C++: ./main < test

Python: python main.py < test

Comment: You don't need semicolons in Python FYI.

Comment: In what world C++ does it differently?

Comment: I think you're confused with what constitutes standard input. Standard input is what's provided on the command line when you invoke the program. You're just reading what the user types in the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your syntax, I assume you're using python 2.

Use `raw_input` to read a string from the console and then manually split it before parsing your ints:

```
s = raw_input()
tokens = s.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sys.argv which is similar to many other programming languages:

```
import sys

for a in sys.argv:
    print a
```

If you invoke this program from the command line like this:

```
python test.py 10 20 30 40 50
```

Then it will print:

```
test.py
10
20
30
40
50
```

So you can just access your arguments using indexes:

```
print sys.argv[2] #prints 20
```

Remember though that sys.argv contains strings - so if you want to handle the input like integers remember to cast them first like this:

```
int(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. If I try to run the program using python test.py < input_file, all the content of the file goes to sys.argv[]?

Comment: No it will not. If I were you I would just run "python test.py input_file" and then open the file within the program itself.